# Adding a directory to tomcat classpath and read the property file in spring

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat7

I am trying to read the `test1.properties` file which is located at an external folder.

here is my spring config file:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer3" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:test.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:test1.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

if I place the `test1.properties` in the `tomcat7/lib` folder, I am able to read it.
However, I want to place it in a different directory as `tomcat7/env/test1.properties`

I have added the path to the  the `conf/catalina.properties`:

```
common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/env
```

This its not working, please help

---

**solution:**
Ok.. finally fixed  it.. I had been doing it correctly this whole time.. it was my IDE which caused the problem.
The IDE was not picking up the changes in the `catalina.properties` file. I had to delete the server config in my IDE and re configure it.

these links were helpful in general:

- [Adding a directory to tomcat classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300780/adding-a-directory-to-tomcat-classpath)
- http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-classpath#solutions

Comment: You could also use the `file:` prefix to point to a file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with classpath between Eclipse, Tomcat and JUnit in Spring 3 app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179767/problems-with-classpath-between-eclipse-tomcat-and-junit-in-spring-3-app)

Comment: The question is answered in the comments.

See 
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments

Answer (score 4):

Ok.. finally fixed it.. I had been doing it correctly this whole time.. it was my IDE which caused the problem. The IDE was not picking up the changes in the catalina.properties file. I had to delete the server config in my IDE and re configure it.

these links were helpful in general:

Adding a directory to tomcat classpath

http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-classpath#solutions

Answer (score 3):

Use setenv.sh in the bin directory. If the file doesn't exist, create it.
To add something to the classpath use the following syntax:

```
CLASSPATH=/yourdir/
```

For windows: setenv.bat

Solution: creating the setenv.bat file under tomcat bin folder helped me in WINDOWS.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention to keep file outside the war or ear , so that you can update it without compling and creating war again. just editing the file and restarting the server. Keep it in any external folder , even outside server and give absolute path in spring.

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer3" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
<property name="locations">
    <list>
        <value>classpath:test.properties</value>
        <value>**file:/someexteranal/dir/test1.properties**</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

Best thing , you can give this / path with root in Unix/linux and same will work in windows, just need to keep file in directory where your server is installed.
Like your tomcat in D drive , then keep it in D:\someexternal\dir and above code will work fine there too