# How to add external resources (properties file) on to the classpath so that war can read?

Tags: java, tomcat, classpath

We have small problem in adding the external directory (having config.properties)  to the classpath. If we add this to the classpath, we should be able to read it in the web application. There are some spring applications in web application which will read the external properties file. I don't find the correct solution any where ? Could you please point me the right direction ?

Thanks,
Rama Krishna

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17670826/adding-a-directory-to-tomcat-classpath-and-read-the-property-file-in-spring and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300780/adding-a-directory-to-tomcat-classpath

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar requirement and I did the followings:

1) Added the properties folder path against shared.loader in catalina.properties.
   Example:

```
    shared.loader="c:/ExternalResource"
```

2) Then read the properties using the following :-

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propertiesFileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **tomcat**, you can edit **conf/catalina.properties**, and append your properties folder in  **common.loader**, like:

```
common.loader=...${catalina.base}/myPropertiesFolder
```

Comment: I have one file in C:\abs\config.properties. How can I add this on to the classpath ? Some one is guiding from this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300780/adding-a-directory-to-tomcat-classpath) like set CLASSPATH=C:\abs\config.properties. Does that work ?

Comment: @RamaKrishna.G, sorry I have not used `set CLASSPATH=`, for our project we are using `catalina.properties` for extra properties. but I think `CLASSPATH` it should can work.

Comment: If I want to use catalina.properties to add my directory, how can I do that ? Can you share me a piece of code ?

Answer (score 0):

It may be sufficient just to copy the properties file to `tomcat\lib` directory as `tomcat\conf\catalina.properties` already contains `common.loader="${catalina.base}/lib","${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar"`.

So `lib` populates to classpath not only any contained jar contents but all contained files too.

See [Tomcat Class Loader HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html).